# jQuery datatables column filter breaks due to ampersand (&) in columns

Tags: datatables

I have set up default column filtering for my table but in 1 column the td cels contains a value (e.g. "merger & aquisitions") which breaks the filtering. how can I handle this?

Comment: I am not sure what you specifically mean by "_default column filtering_" or by "_breaks the filtering_", but I can filter data containing an ampersand correctly using [column filters](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html).

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?